# Expressjs main loop blocked during intense operation

Tags: node.js, express, concurrency

I'm having an expressjs server running in which an endpoint `init` performs some intense operation that has an average completion time of 10 seconds. During these 10 seconds, the main loop is "stuck", making it impossible to send requests to the expressjs server. I've been googling for a while now but found nothing which would enable expressjs to handle requests concurrently. It would seem silly if this is not possible. For any hints or help, I'm very thankful.

Example code:

routes.js

```js
app.route('/v1/cv/random').get(init);
```

features/init.js

```js
module.exports = async function init(req, res) {
    try {
        // perform some time consuming operation here
        res.status(201).send(someVar);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(`failed to init`).end();
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you add some relevant code?

Comment: @eol I've added some example code.

Comment: We need to see the "time-consuming operation" in detail.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I am generating cryptographic key pairs using RSA. Depending on what initialisation is taking place, it may be executed up to 30 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to implement algorithms with long running time in a synchronous manner, for example the [Tower of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi):

```js
function move(from, to, via, n) {
  if (n > 1)
    move(from, via, to, n - 1);
  to.unshift(from.shift());
  if (n > 1)
    move(via, to, from, n - 1);
}
app.get("/tower", function(req, res) {
  var a = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < Number(req.query.n); i++) a.push(i);
  var b = [];
  var c = [];
  move(a, b, c, a.length);
  res.end("Done");
});
```

Invoking `GET /tower?n=<N>` with large enough `<N>` will indeed block the main loop of express.

This blocking can be avoided by introducing asynchronousness into the algorithm, for example with `setTimeout(nextAlgorithmicStep)` commands. This puts the `nextAlgorithmicStep` function in a queue, but the same queue also has room for functions that process concurrent requests:

```js
function tick(from, to, via, n) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      move(from, to, via, n, resolve);
    });
  });
}
async function move(from, to, via, n, resolve) {
  if (n > 1)
    await tick(from, via, to, n - 1);
  to.unshift(from.shift());
  if (n > 1)
    await tick(via, to, from, n - 1);
  resolve();
}
app.get("/tower", async function(req, res) {
  var a = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < Number(req.query.n); i++) a.push(i);
  var b = [];
  var c = [];
  await tick(a, b, c, a.length);
  res.end("Done");
});
```

With this, you can you wait (forever) for the request `GET /tower?n=64` to come back, but you can at least still make concurrent requests to the same server. (Using simply `Promise` or [`process.nextTick`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/process.html#processnexttickcallback-args) instead of `setTimeout` is not "asynchronous enough" to allow concurrent requests to be processed in between.)

However, the execution of `GET /tower?n=10`, which finished "immediately" in the first version, now takes much longer. It would be better to use the `setTimeout` not on all `n` levels of recursion, but only on every tenth level or so. You have to find similar good points for asynchronousness in your RSA algorithm.

---

That's what you can do with a single-threaded Node.js program. But there is an alternative that uses [multiple Node.js processes](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html).

```js
app.get("/tower", function(req, res) {
  spawn("node", ["tower.js", req.query.n]).stdout.pipe(res);
});
```

where `tower.js` is an additional Javascript program:

```js
function move(from, to, via, n) {
  if (n > 1)
    move(from, via, to, n - 1);
  to.unshift(from.shift());
  if (n > 1)
    move(via, to, from, n - 1);
}

var a = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Number(process.argv[2]); i++) a.push(i);
var b = [];
var c = [];
move(a, b, c, a.length);
process.stdout.write("Done");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. The main loop is still blocked when I wrap the key generation inside a timeout within a promise.

Comment: It does not help if you wrap the _entire_ key generation in a `setTimeout`. You must somehow cut it into slices with a `setTimeout` between one slice and the next.

Comment: Alternatively, carry out the key generation in a [separate thread](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/cluster.html).

Comment: I have augmented my answer with an implementation that uses a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer shortly before @Heiko Theißen updated his answer. It is (I think) a similar approach.

I've found a way to use `child_process` and with that execute everything that a certain file has by using

```js
const {fork} = require('child_process');

...

module.exports = async function init(req, res) {
    try {
        const childProcess = fork('./path/to/the/script.js');

        childProcess.send({'body': req.body});
        childProcess.on('message', (message) => {
            res.status(201).json({someVar: message}).end();
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(`failed to init`).end();
    }
};
```

The `script.js` looks like

```js
process.on('message', async (message) => {
    // perform a time consuming operation here
    process.send(someVar);
    process.exit();
});
```