# Why would a screen, while still loading, wait before redirecting to a new screen if a user has already clicked a link to that new screen

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

I have a screen that loads a lot of data from the Server while it loads, it also has some JS running of course. Early the page loading process, a link becomes available for the user that they can click and it will take them to a different screen. I would expect that as they click the link it would immediately redirect them to the new screen. However, after they click it, it seems to wait for some of the data fetches from the server to rust before navigating to that new screen - either this or it is waiting for JS to finish perhaps - I am unsure of the reason for the delay - and this is the question: what is causing this delay (it is definately related to the screen still loading) and is there a way I can force the redirect to happen immediately.
Thanks

Since it is basic functionality I have not been able to try anything but to look in the Dev Tools to see what is happening with the network calls - which is seems to wait for a few to come back before redirecting.

Comment: If you have `<body onload="long_running()">` where `long_running` is a long-running _synchronous_ function like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73022654/16462950), you cannot interact with the page while this is still running. Javascript is single-threaded.

Comment: Hi @HeikoTheißen thanks for your response. I am not sure about the function running there - I am using a low code platform so I can't see what is happening there. But I can still interact with the screen while it is loading so I don't think it is blocking.

Comment: Can you inspect the page with DevTools while the script is running? Can you see where the link actually points to while the script is running?